# Use inheritance when creating objects

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

I need a bit of a hand, I'm writing a program that's fundamentally a little shop. I have different items here under the class `Content`, which looks like this:

```
public abstract class Content {

    // Content Attributes
    private String contentID;
    private String contentName;
    private double applicationPrice;
    private int downloadCount;

    //private Comments[] comments = new Comments[100];
    //private int commentCount= 0;


    // Constructor
    public Content(String ID, String Name, double price) {
        this.contentID = ID;
        this.contentName = Name;
        this.applicationPrice= price;

    }

    public Content(String ID, String Name) {
        this.contentID = ID;
        this.contentName = Name;
        this.applicationPrice= 0;

    }


    // Accessor Methods
    public String getID() {
        return contentID;
    }
    public double getApplicationPrice() {
        return applicationPrice;
    }


    public String getContentName() {
        return contentName;
    }

    public void download() {
        //code to make a download happen
        //++ download

        return;
    }

    public void addComment() {
        //scanner input comment

        //this.comments[commentCount]= my new comment;
    }




}
```

Under content I have other classes that extend it such as `Application` and `Publication` (`Publication` is further extended by `Book` and `Magazine`). As an example `Application` looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application extends Content {
    // attributes

    private String osType;

    //constructor

    public Application(String ID, String name, double price, String os) {

        super(ID, name, price);

        this.osType = os;
    }

    public Application(String ID, String name, String os) {
        super(ID, name);
        this.osType = os;

    }


    //accessor methods


    public String getOsType() {
        return this.osType;
    }




    }
```

My issue is that I think there's a problem with my fundamental understanding of inheritance in practice. I want to understand how best I can allow my user to create these objects. So far I have a `MyShop` class where they can create an application:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyShop {
    // instance variables that you need (marked as private)

    // declare a private array to store content here
    private Content[] contentList = new Content[100];
    private int contentCount = 0;

    // declare a private array to store users here

    public MyShop() {

    }



    public void addApplication(){

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        String appID;
        String appName;
        double appPrice;
        String appOS;
        int control = 0;

        while(control== 0) {
            try {
                System.out.println("What is the ID of the Application?");
                appID = console.next();

                System.out.println("What is the name of the Application?");
                appName = console.next();

                System.out.println("What is the price of the Application?");
                appPrice = console.nextDouble();

                System.out.println("What is the minimum OS of the Application?");
                appOS = console.next();

                Application newApplication= new Application(appID, appName, appPrice, appOS);
                System.out.println(newApplication.getApplicationPrice());
                contentList[contentCount] = newApplication;
                contentCount++;
                console.close();
                control = 1;
            }catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("invalid input try again!"); 
            }

        }


    }




    public void showContent() {
        System.out.println(contentList);
    }


//  public void addUser(....) {
//      // code here
//  }


    // space for other possible methods here
}
```

Is there a way I can use inheritance to avoid having to have a `addBook()` and `addMagazine()` in addition to `addApplication()` and instead have something generic like `addContent()`?

Please let me know if my question is unclear or if more information is needed!

Answer (score 1):

Rethink your model, it should match how it works in the real world. Your shop *sells* items, it's not a manufactorer. So the shop class will never *create* an application. It will *have* a pool of sellable things. Products. A stock. And some products are applications, some are books, some are magazines, cars, shampoos, whatever.

Rename `Content` to `StockItem`. `contentId` would be `itemId`, `contentName` `itemName` or just `name`. A model is easier (far easier!) to understand if it matches the real world.

Then, add a `Stock` class, which has all the items (a `List<StockItem> items` for a *very*  simple first approach). The Stock will have some methods, like

```
public StockItem findById(String stockItemId);
public List<StockItem> findAllByName(String name);
public void addItem(StockItem newItem);
public void itemsSold(String stockItemID, int quantity);
//...
```

Now if you want to add a book to the stock, simply call

```
addItem(new Book("Clean Code", "Robert Martin"));
```

while this book is a stockitem:

```
public class Publication extends StockItem { ... }
public class Book extends Publication { ... }
```

Later, you'd learn that this simplified model is not production ready, there are better solutions for real shops, but the message would be: start with a good model. Look at the real world, describe what you see and use exactly that to build your classes and add the methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make interface with method `addContent(int mode)` with 3 integers inside with names `APPLICATION, BOOK, MAGAZINE` and then implement it to your `myShop` class. According to `int mode` you make realization of method addContent.

Answer (score 0):

[Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#Java) solves exactly this problem.
You can create a method:

```java
<T extends Content> void addContent(Class<T> contentClass) {
  if (Application.class.equals(contentClass)) {
  ... 
  } else if ...

  } else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unknown Content type");
  }
}
```

Or

```java
void addContent(ContentType contentType) {
  switch (contentType) {
    case APPLICATION:
       ...
    case ...
    default:
      throw new RuntimeException("Unknown Content type")
  }
}
```

```java
public enum ContentType {
  APPLICATION, BOOK, MAGAZINE;
}
```